Mounting shelf tracks on drywall over furring strips over masonry?
I would like to install adjustable shelves on hanging tracks in a basement room. That room has a layer of drywall mounted to a furring strip frame (~3/4 in thick) on a masonry wall.
I'm sure I don't want to mount the hang track on drywall only. I don't know exactly how the furring strips were attached to the masonry, it was possibly only done to hold the drywall, not any heavy shelves.
My idea was now to drill through the furring strips all the way into the masonry and use plastic anchors in there, to hold up the hang track. I was also thinking about mounting a 1x3 board first, so I have more space vertically, and then screw the hang track into the board. I would need some spacers along the hanging shelf tracks, but that's not a problem.
Is that a good idea? Are there other options? What kind of anchor am I looking for - I'm from Europe and I couldn't find the masonry anchors that I know in the big box stores.

Can you buy Tapcons in your area?

I agree with anchoring to the masonry. Whether tapcons or equivalent are the best answer depends on the kind of masonry; they are good for concrete, but I'm not convinced they're the right choice for brick.

I've used masonry screws into brick  this was to attach a carport to a house wall, they worked well.

Yes, Tapcons are available (I'm in a Washington, DC, suburb), but I'm pretty sure the wall is cinder block and not solid concrete.

Drilling through the furring is a good idea.
Plastic anchors (that accept screws) should be strong enough to support aluminum shelf tracks (which themselves are not particularly strong - fine for displaying ornaments and trophies, but not suited for a bookshelf)
plastic pin anchors are another option, and others have suggested masonry screws that's another option.
Expanding bolts, glue-in anchors, metal pin anchors, and powder actuated nails are the "nuclear" options not needed for lightweight shelving.
